# Pig: Illustrate error 2997

Tags: apache-pig

Below code is working fine and producing the results at the grunt (local mode) except the illustrate on last relation is giving the error 2997

/* Open Grunt in local mode pig -x local */

```
STOCK_A= LOAD '/media/sf_sand/NYSE_daily_prices_A.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (exchange:chararray,symbol:chararray,date:chararray,open:float,high:float,low:float,close:float,volume:int,adj_close:float); 
describe STOCK_A;
illustrate STOCK_A;
b= LIMIT STOCK_A 100;
describe b;
illustrate b;
c= FOREACH b GENERATE *;
illustrate c is working
c= FOREACH b GENERATE symbol,date,close;
dump c;  — working
```

Illustrate c is not working below is the error ( Error 2997 Encountered IO exception):

```
015-06-10 11:52:23,621 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
2015-06-10 11:52:23,647 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2015-06-10 11:52:23,647 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[ConstantCalculator, LoadTypeCastInserter, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter]}
2015-06-10 11:52:23,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2015-06-10 11:52:23,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-06-10 11:52:23,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-06-10 11:52:23,651 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2015-06-10 11:52:23,651 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2015-06-10 11:52:23,658 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2015-06-10 11:52:23,658 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2015-06-10 11:52:23,658 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Distributed cache not supported or needed in local mode. Setting key [pig.schematuple.local.dir] with code temp directory: /tmp/1433937143658-0
2015-06-10 11:52:23,667 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2015-06-10 11:52:23,669 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: STOCK_A[3,9] C:  R:
2015-06-10 11:52:23,672 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-06-10 11:52:23,672 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-06-10 11:52:23,705 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2015-06-10 11:52:23,707 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-06-10 11:52:23,707 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-06-10 11:52:23,708 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2015-06-10 11:52:23,708 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2015-06-10 11:52:23,708 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Reduce phase detected, estimating # of required reducers.
2015-06-10 11:52:23,709 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting Parallelism to 1
2015-06-10 11:52:23,723 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: STOCK_A[3,9],STOCK_A[-1,-1],c[8,3] C:  R: b[4,3]
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [115, 116, 111, 99, 107, 95, 112, 114, 105, 99, 101, 95, 111, 112, 101, 110] in field being converted to float, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "stock_price_open"> field discarded
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [115, 116, 111, 99, 107, 95, 112, 114, 105, 99, 101, 95, 104, 105, 103, 104] in field being converted to float, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "stock_price_high"> field discarded
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [115, 116, 111, 99, 107, 95, 112, 114, 105, 99, 101, 95, 108, 111, 119] in field being converted to float, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "stock_price_low"> field discarded
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [115, 116, 111, 99, 107, 95, 112, 114, 105, 99, 101, 95, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101] in field being converted to float, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "stock_price_close"> field discarded
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [115, 116, 111, 99, 107, 95, 118, 111, 108, 117, 109, 101] in field being converted to int, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "stock_volume"> field discarded
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [115, 116, 111, 99, 107, 95, 112, 114, 105, 99, 101, 95, 97, 100, 106, 95, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101] in field being converted to float, caught NumberFormatException <For input string: "stock_price_adj_close"> field discarded
java.lang.ClassCastException
2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your log, you have the following error :

```
Unable to interpret value [115, 116, 111, 99, 107, 95, 112, 114, 105, 99, 101, 95, 97, 100, 106, 95, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101] in field being converted to float, caught NumberFormatException field discarded java.lang.ClassCastException 2015-06-10 11:52:23,727 [main]
```

Could you provide a sample of you csv file as I think event `STOCK_A` is not okay ?

You may also `LIMIT` the input to few lines, and show the results of `DESCRIBE` and `DUMP` on those lines.